# Странное поведение state при отслеживании события

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Login() {
    const [hand, setHand] = useState('Загрузка...');
    const [type, setType] = useState('log');
    function submitHandler(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        if (typeof type !== 'string') {
            return setHand('Произошла ошибка');
        }
        console.log(`type="${type}"`);
    }      
    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="login"}>
            <div className="buttons">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="button-styled reg"
                >
                    Зарегистрироваться
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => setType('reg')}
                    type="submit"
                    className="button-styled log"
                >
                    Войти
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => setType('log')}
                    type="reset"
                    className="button-styled"
                >
                    Сбросить
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

При на кнопки я переопределяю `type` и в функции, передаваемой коллбеком (`submitHandler`) в `onSubmit` формы консолю. Но консолится оно странно: в случае нажатия на `Зарегистрироваться` всегда выводится `log`, пока не нажимаю на `Войти`, тогда выводится `reg` и во все последующие разы вне зависимости от кнопки.

Пробовал переписать функцию так:

```js
function submitHandler() {
  return function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    if (typeof type !== 'string') {
      return setHand('Произошла ошибка');
    }
    console.log(`type="${type}"`);
  }
}
```

И уже не передавать, а вызывать `submitHandler` в `onSubmit`, но тогда почему-то не работает `ev.preventDefault()`.

Comment: хуки же не синхронные. у тебя submitHandler начинает выполняться до того как завершился setType

Comment: @nörbörnën,а исправить то как можно?

Comment: @nörbörnën, пробовал async/await, не помогло

Comment: у тебя форма авторизации/регистрации. логин, пароль, разные сценарии и т.д. выбранный пользовательский сценарий ("авторизация","регистрация") не является стейтом этого компонента. вообще. тебе нужно input, input, <button onClick={loginHandler}, <button onClick={registerHandler}. короче, ты производишь какую-то чушь. исправить её можно, но ты лучше ложись спать. а завтра, на свежую голову, потрать время на просмотр __нормального__ гайда с формой авторизации, например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivDjWYcKDZI

Comment: забыл. вот на те "input,input" стейт нужен, `const [ form, setForm ] = useState({email: '', password: ''});` а `<form>` как раз не нужен. сам по себе ` <form>`, - это такой state из 90x, забудь о нём когда используешь фреймворки типа react